# Connecting to a gallery without typing in page name

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I'm working on a website where I have users view their gallery by typing in "www.example.com/mygallery" As of now they way I have this working is I create a virtual directory called "mygallery", and upload all the project files to it. This works well enough, but it's kind of clunky. Ideally what I would like to do is have the user type in the url (www.example.com/mygallery), and the website goes to "www.example.com/galllery.aspx?name=mygallery". That way there is no need to create a virtual directory for every user.

I have posted a similar question not too long ago about this, but I specifically said I wanted to use url rewriting to accomplish this goal, and did not get any responses. However I am open to any method of accomplishing this. So any help on this subject is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Url rewriting is the way to go. Using ASP.NET MVC makes it effortless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site isn't MVC, you can still use the RouteCollection mechanism to handle URL re-writing. Check this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx

Comment: That was it! thank you very much. Very easy to implement, and so far works like a charm.